# Pass Golang Variables into Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to pass my Golang variables into a Javascript file. I have read multiple articles online, including [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript). I feel like I'm pretty close, but alas the most eloquent implementation to this problem eludes me.

I'm looking for a simple and elegant solution that **injects an object value in Go with a variable in Javascript**. I feel like this is a very common problem, so the lack of a clear tutorial on this surprises me.

My first file [server.go] servers an HTML page using the templating libraries in Golang passing in a context and serving them through Handlers.

```
type PassStruct struct{
    data    []int
    number1 int
    number2 int
}

//inject the structure into render
func render(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, context Context){
       //parse context and fill in templating variables using template 
 }
```

I now have an HTML document that is served, which adds a Javascript file to it.

```
 <html>
     <head>
     //import javascript file 
     </head>
     <body>
     //some body
     </body>
 </html>
```

Finally, the javascript file is what I am really interested in:

```
  var data; //some 
  var number1;
  var number2;

  function doSomething(){
  }
```

I need to send the PassStruct into the Javascript file, and map out each of the values within the structure to a variable in the Javascript file. I have tried AJAX calls, but have not had success so far.

Comment: For most templating languages JSON encoding is the safest way, see https://gobyexample.com/json

Comment: so did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Finally , after spending 2 days on the problem , i found an elegant way to work around it .
We will use templates to solve this problem .

Read about templates usage in golang here -
[Understanding Templates with Examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/templates-in-golang/)  .

Here is a sample code to pass a golang variable called ***golangVar*** in javascript .

HTML_File -

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var golangVar = "{{.}}"
        console.log(golangVar);
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <!--some body-->
 </body>
</html>
```

Golang HttpHandler -

**Make sure you include "*html/template*" library in the golang code .**

```
func golangHttpHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
var golangVar string 
golangVar = "ProblemSolved" 
templ, err := template.ParseFiles("/home/PathToHTMLPage/HTML_File.html")
if(err!=nil){
    fmt.Println("Error = ",err)
}
err = templ.Execute(w, golangVar)
if(err!=nil){
    fmt.Println("Error = ",err)
}   
}
```

Also, a bonus tip -
If you are working around with buffalo framework for golang , you can use default plush package for templating .
Its similar to what we have done here with just a little bit of change in syntax and passing of html file  .
Read -
[Templating in Buffalo Framework](https://gobuffalo.io/en/docs/templating)

Comment: That's how i got rid of the stupid javascript errors in my Code editor! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This way maybe helpful:

Html:

```
<html>
    <head>
     <!--import javascript file -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/myjs.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            myFunc({{.}});
        </script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <!--some body-->
     </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:(myjs.js)

```
function myFunc(passStruct){
    var obj = Object();

    var data = passStruct.Data;
    var number1=passStruct.Number1;
    var number2=passStruct.Number2;

    obj.data=data;
    obj.number1=number1;
    obj.number2=number2;

    return obj;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own template function and use it to marshal struct into json.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72126401/11289618).